# PHP variable usage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have PHP file with a variable called $username. Here's my script below:

```
<script> 
var chat = new Chat(<?php echo $username;?>);                           
</script>
```

But it's not working. I am new to PHP. Let me know what I am missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, PHP will execute. In your code it just pastes value of `$username`. Then javascript will execute. So you have to write:

```
var chat = new Chat('<?php echo $username;?>'); // with quotes
```

But much better to use AJAX or Fetch and get value asynchronously. With this approach you can do it from any `.js` file, but your code will execute only in `.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

It helped me several times to have everything echoed by PHP

```
<?php
echo "<script>";
echo "var chat = new Chat(".$username.");";                           
echo "</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to echo the script tags like this:

```
echo '<script>'; 
echo 'var chat = new Chat(' . $username . ')';                           
echo '</script>';
```